# Function call and interrupt another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three buttons, each of which calls two functions jquery,one for display and one for close, pictures.

Inside the function to open, I have a list of sequential functions. However, it may happen that the User click a button and a function has not completed the list and click on it nother button.

So I need to call a function and interrupt another, anyone know how to do?

I am using jquery animate

Comment: When you say 'distrupt another function', do you actually mean 'stop the animation another function is causing from happening'?

Comment: look at `.stop()` to do this http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: I must be blind but i cannot see any of your function code.

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I need to call a function and interrupt another, anyone know how to do?

You can't literally do that, because JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (barring the use of [Web Workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), but you only have on UI thread even then). So you can't interrupt the execution of a function call.

But if you're using jQuery's animation/effects functions, the calls you make just put actions in a queue that jQuery then runs asynchronously, and you *can* interrupt that, by calling [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) on the element.

So by way of example:

```
function kickThingsOff() {
    // These could all be written in one line as a chain, but I'm doing them
    // separately for emphasis
    var elm = $("#myElement");
    elm.fadeOut("slow");
    elm.fadeIn("slow");
    elm.slideUp("slow");
}

function interruptIt() {
    $("#myElement").stop(true, true);
}
```

You can't actually interrupt `kickThingsOff` in the middle (between, say, the `fadeIn` line and the `slideUp` line), but you can interrupt the *animation* it queues up via `stop`.

Comment: I'm using animations images, but image is not fixed but several images over a background, an image arrives and another comes.
I will using "stop". But if anyone keep clicking several times on the buttons, the javascript will end up, losing himself. Anyway thanks for the clarification!